# Running a python command with terminal-generated signals enabled

Tags: terminal, vimscript-python

I'm trying to do a long blocking read call inside a python script supplied with the `python` command:

```
python3 << EOF
import ctypes
libc=ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
ch = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1)
r = libc.read(3,ch,1) #raw syscall, because pythons os.read restarts on EINTR
EOF
```

I would like for the `read` call to be breakable with signal-generated signals such as `SIGINT` (generated by `Ctrl+C`).

Unfortunately, vim seems to run the python snippet with the terminal set not to generated this signal upon a `Ctrl+C`.

How can I run this snippet so that `Ctlr+C` continues to generates `SIGINT` even inside of the snippet? Also, how can the vimscript that calls the python snippet tell if the python succeeded or not?